# Implementing digital controller in the time domain

Tags: matlab, control-theory, simulation, linear-control

I have simulated a digital control system in the Z domain using MATLAB and I have got satisfactory results. However, when I converted the plant and the digital controller to difference equations and implemented them in an m-file, I did not get the same results displayed in the Z domain

In the Z domain, my system is stable and the response to a unit step met certain desired specifications, but in time domain, the response goes to infinity:

Below you find the program in the Z domain then in the time domain:

1. Z domain simulation:

```
clear all
close all

J = 0.01;                           % moment of inertia of the rotor       0.01 kg.m^2
b = 0.1;                            % motor viscous friction constant      0.1 N.m.s
K = 0.01;                           % electromotive force constant         0.01 V/rad/sec
                                    % motor torque constant                0.01 N.m/Amp
R = 1;                              % electric resistance                  1 Ohm
L = 0.5;                            % electric inductance                  0.5 H
s = tf('s');
P_motor = K/((J*s+b)*(L*s+R)+K^2)   % Open loop Transfer function of a Dc motor Speed/Voltage
zpk(P_motor)

%rP_motor=0.1/(0.5*s+1)              % First Order approximation of P_motor
Ts = 0.05;
dP_motor = c2d(P_motor, Ts, 'zoh');

zpk(dP_motor)

sys_cl = feedback(dP_motor,1);
[y,t] = step(sys_cl,1);
stairs(t,y);
xlabel('Time (s)')
ylabel('Velocity (rad/s)')
title('Stairstep Response: Original')

Kp = 100;
Ki = 200;
Kd = 10;

C = Kp + Ki/s + Kd*s;
PI=Kp+Ki/s;
PD=Kp+Kd*s;
dC1 = c2d(C,Ts,'tustin')
dPI=c2d(PI,Ts,'tustin');
dPD=c2d(PD,Ts,'tustin');

sys_cl = feedback(dC1*dP_motor,1);
[x2,t] = step(sys_cl,12);
stairs(t,x2)
xlabel('Time (seconds)')
ylabel('Velocity (rad/s)')
title('Stairstep Response: with PID controller')

rlocus(dC1*dP_motor)
axis([-1.5 1.5 -1 1])
title('Root Locus of Compensated System')

z = tf('z',Ts);
dC = dC1/(z+0.82);
rlocus(dC*dP_motor);
axis([-1.5 1.5 -1 1])
title('Root Locus of Compensated System');


sys_cl = feedback(0.8*dC*dP_motor,1);
[x3,t] = step(sys_cl,8);
stairs(t,x3)
xlabel('Time (seconds)')
ylabel('Velocity (rad/s)')
title('Stairstep Response: with Modified PID controller')
```

Unit step response according to this simulation:
[image]

2. Time domain simulation (using difference equations)

```
close all;

%Output initial condition
yk=0;yk_1=0;yk_2=0;
%Controller initial condition of 
uk_3=0;  uk_2=0;  uk_1=0;  uk=0;          
%Error initial condition
ek_3=0;  ek_2=0;  ek_1=0;  ek=0;  
%Sampling Time
Ts=0.05;

%Desired output (unit step)
yd=1;

%Stokage of different variables (yk, uk and time)
stokuk=[0];
stokyk=[0];
temps=[0];

%******Z Transform of the plant*****%
%     0.002059 z + 0.001686         %
%     ----------------------        %
%     z^2 - 1.511 z + 0.5488        %
%                                   %
%***********************************%

%***Z Transforme of the Controller**%
%    404 z^2 - 632 z + 244          %
%   -------------------------       %
%   z^3 + 0.82 z^2 - z - 0.82       %
%                                   %
%***********************************%



%Calculation of 
for t=[0:Ts:12]
    t;
    
    ek=yd-yk;
    uk=(404*ek_1)-(632*ek_2)+(244*ek_3)-(0.82*uk_1)+(uk_2)+(0.82*uk_3);
    yk=(1.511*yk_1)-(0.5488*yk_2)+(0.002059*uk_1)+(0.001686*uk_2);
    yk_2=yk_1;
    yk_1=yk;
    uk_3=uk_2;
    uk_2=uk_1;
    uk_1=uk;
    ek_3=ek_2;
    ek_2=ek_1;
    ek_1=ek;
    
    stokyk=[stokyk;yk];
    stokuk=[stokuk;uk];
    temps=[temps;t];
     
end

plot(temps,stokyk);grid on
hold on
plot(temps,stokuk);grid on
```

Unit step response in the time domain:

[image]

Could anyone please explain to me why I get this difference in simulations?

Comment: How did you discretize your system? Via bilinear transform?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo The plant is discretized using 'zoh' method  and the controller is discretized using 'Tustin' method, as it is showed in the first program

Comment: How did you pick the sampling frequency?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo the dominant pole of the plant (approximately equal to 2). Therefore, choosing a sampling period of 0.05 seconds is significantly faster than the dynamics of the plant. This sampling period is also fast compared to the speed that will be achieved by the resultant closed-loop system.

Comment: It seems that the $z$-transform of your controller does not correspond to any of the previous controllers. Also, your implementation of the time-domain simulation is prove to errors. The best is to convert the transfer function into a state-space form using tf2ss and use the matrices for the implementation. This way, if you change the controller, your code will remain pretty much the same.

Comment: @KBS The Z transform of the controller is 0.8*dC, and is the controller used in the last closed loop system named sys_cl in the program, so the problem does not come from this fact, because even if I tak dC as it is, without the gain 0.8, I got something different than of that of Z-domain

Answer (score 5):

Your error is subtle but has a dramatic effect on the stability of the system. Note that we have

$$
e_k = y_d - y_k
$$

So you have to compute the error **after** computing the system output in your loop. If you do it before (like in your code) this is equivalent to adding a time delay of one sample step to your control loop, which in this case is already enough to destroy closed loop stability.

The correct implementation would look like this (copy/pasting most of the code from your question):

```
close all;

%Output initial condition
yk=0;yk_1=0;yk_2=0;
%Controller initial condition of 
uk_3=0;  uk_2=0;  uk_1=0;  uk=0;          
%Error initial condition
ek_3=0;  ek_2=0;  ek_1=0;  ek=0;  
%Sampling Time
Ts=0.05;

%Desired output (unit step)
yd=1;

%Stokage of different variables (yk, uk and time)
stokuk=[0]; stokyk=[0]; temps=[0];

%Calculation of 
for t=[0:Ts:12]
    t;

    uk=(404*ek_1)-(632*ek_2)+(244*ek_3)-(0.82*uk_1)+(uk_2)+(0.82*uk_3);
    yk=(1.511*yk_1)-(0.5488*yk_2)+(0.002059*uk_1)+(0.001686*uk_2);
    ek=yd-yk; % Compute the control error here, not before yk!

    yk_2=yk_1;
    yk_1=yk;
    uk_3=uk_2;
    uk_2=uk_1;
    uk_1=uk;
    ek_3=ek_2;
    ek_2=ek_1;
    ek_1=ek;
    
    stokyk=[stokyk;yk];
    stokuk=[stokuk;uk];
    temps=[temps;t];
     
end

subplot(2,1,1); stairs(temps,stokyk);grid on;xlabel('t');ylabel('y');ylim([0,1.2]);
subplot(2,1,2); stairs(temps,stokuk);grid on;xlabel('t');ylabel('u');
```

With this code you get:

[image]

which reproduces the step response from your first script.

---

Just one more side note: Having a closed loop system that is so sensitive to such a small increase in the loop delay will likely cause problems in practice. For the sake of robustness you usually want your controller to still be able to stabilize the system even when the delay increases a bit.

You can also see this if you look at the control input $u$ in the figure above: the control signal is oscillating heavily, which is usually undesired.

So if you plan to apply this digital controller in the real world, I would recommend to redesign your controller, with the goal to increase the delay margin of your system.